# Shiny Websocket Idle Timeout

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I'm running a shiny app using the command:

```
shiny::runApp("./app",8080,FALSE,"0.0.0.0")
```

The app works fine but when running it behind a load balancer the websocket connection gets dropped after 60 seconds because neither the client (web browser) nor the server are sending data. This is due to an unchangeable timeout in the load balancer. Is there some way to get shiny to send a heartbeat message over the websocket every `n` seconds? Has anyone an idea how to solve this question?